# Set selected item on ContextMenu open action wp7

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, contextmenu

How I can set selected item or get listbox item in which I have ContextMenu?

```
                   <local:TypeTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">
                  <local:TypeTemplateSelector.WithAudio>
                    <DataTemplate>
                      <Grid Margin="0,5">
                        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                          <toolkit:ContextMenu Open="needselect"  x:Name="databoundMenu">
                            <toolkit:MenuItem  Header="I Like It"/>
                            <toolkit:MenuItem>
                              <toolkit:MenuItem.Header>
                                <CheckBox Content="Tell" ></CheckBox>
                              </toolkit:MenuItem.Header>
                            </toolkit:MenuItem>
                          </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        <StackPanel>
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding h}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                      </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                  </local:TypeTemplateSelector.WithAudio>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question: you have a listbox in which each item has a contextmenu and in the context menu you want to know the selected item ? Here's  my usage of the contextmenu

```
<DataTemplate>
<Border>
    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        <toolkit:ContextMenu>
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Move" Command="{Binding MoveCurrentCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"  />
       </toolkit:ContextMenu>
    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,15" Height="100">
    (...)
```

Comment: How I can use it?
For example I have a pid of message and when I need to delete it I try something like "message.remove(pid)".The each of item in listbox contains this pid.({Binding pid})